# Turn range into booleans

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to take a range like

```
SELECT * FROM generate_series(1,5);

generate_series
---------------
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

and turn it into something that looks like

```
false
false
false
false
true
```

where it's always false unless we are on the last row. If it was 0 instead of false and 1 instead of true that would be fine also.

I tried

```
SELECT floor(gs::float / max(gs))
  FROM generate_series(1, 5) AS gs
 GROUP BY gs;
```

but this only returns 1's for some reason which I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html):

```
SELECT
  gs,
  row_number() OVER (ORDER BY gs DESC) = 1
FROM generate_series(1, 5) AS gs
```

Comment: why does this reverse the order of the `generate_series`?

Comment: @NateStemen: If you don't have an explicit `ORDER BY` at the bottom of your query, then the query executor doesn't guarantee any particular ordering. In this case, it would have sorted the results in descending order for the sake of the window, and then returned them as-is (the most efficient approach, given that you didn't ask for a specific order). @wildplasser's answer should keep the ascending order in this contrived example, but for any real-world example, the default ordering should never be relied upon.

Comment: Yea you're totally right, the order doesn't really matter, I just found it easier to look the the data when it was sorted. Thanks for your answer, didn't know about the `OVER` clause.

Answer (score 1):

It is returning 1's because you are always dividing the number by itself. The `max(gs)` isn't doing what you think because you are grouping by `gs`.

You could simply use the `last_value` window function to get what you want, like so:

```
SELECT
    (gs = last_value(gs) over()) AS result
FROM
    generate_series(1,5) gs;
```

Or if you want the max (not necessarily the last - may be one-in-the-same):

```
SELECT
    (gs = max(gs) over()) AS result
FROM
    generate_series(1,5) gs;
```

Comment: `last_value() OVER ()` might work for this toy example, but in general, you can't rely on it without an explicit window ordering (and unfortunately, because `last_value()` is sensitive to the scope of the window frame, you'll need a `RANGE` clause as well).

Comment: `last_value` is pretty self explanatory. It will return the last value of the resulting data set. The OP asks for it to return "always false unless we are on the last row." This does exactly that - always, regardless of the value in that last row.

Comment: Not necessarily. It will return the last value fetched while evaluating the window, but this isn't necessarily the last row in the output (e.g. http://rextester.com/YGKNJD23358). And while OP did say "last row", I think we can safely infer (from the fact that they tried to solve this using `max()`) that they meant "last row in ascending order".

Comment: Obviously if you add an order by desc to it. Guess what? You do the same to your answer and you get the same result: http://rextester.com/UWHMW68937 . So, I'm not sure what you are trying to demonstrate here... Lastly, I have no idea how OP plans to apply this, so I do not try to assume or infer. In either case, I did provide an alternate `max() over()`. If you feel my answer is not correct, please downvote it. Trying to offer a solution to OP, not looking to have to defend every detail of the implementation based on your interpretation of the question.

Comment: I wouldn't say "obviously". The planner is entirely justified in evaluating the window function either before or after the `ORDER BY`, and both of these cases can and do happen, even for the same query over the same data (see http://rextester.com/JGMQ57578 and http://rextester.com/IWLZB25892). What I'm trying to demonstrate is that `last_value()` with an undefined window gives an undefined answer, and while the executor's chosen order might appear to be stable in a specific case, that order is an implementation detail which you should *never* rely on.

Comment: Anyways, sorry if it came across as criticism, just thought the empty window clause deserved a disclaimer (and will gladly upvote if you add this caveat). I've had to debug one too many issues that came down to a reliance on "natural ordering", and it's never fun; the query planner can change its mind at the drop of a hat, so there's often very little to go on when tracking down regression issues (e.g. my examples above, with 100 rows instead of 1000, now give the same answer: http://rextester.com/CCF20524 http://rextester.com/MXU65718).

Comment: Sorry for not being clear about this point: I did say last value, but I was relying on the natural order of things, so i would use the `max` version. Good to know about the `last_value` function though

Comment: @NateStemen: `last_value()` can also give you a deterministic result, but because it depends on the window frame, the window definition gets a little verbose: `gs = last_value(gs) OVER (ORDER BY gs RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)`

Answer (score 1):

Yet another window function:`LEAD()` refers to the *next* row, and is NULL for the final record.

---

```
SELECT (lead(gs) OVER www IS NULL) AS is_last
        FROM generate_series(1,5) gs(gs)
        WINDOW www AS (order by gs)
        ;
```